# I am trying to setup gecko driver and seeing this issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, gecko, geckodriver

Trying to setup gecko driver and seeing this issue , I have added the desirabilities as well as added the environment variable path from the control panel, even those it doesn't resolve my issue

```
1511919812617   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1 (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2017-10-31)
1511919812623   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:28350
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:31.527Z'
System info: host: 'CA3TPCLQA02', ip: '10.101.250.40', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:   0x46c297 - <no info>
   1:   0x4388b6 - <no info>
   2:   0x4225f2 - <no info>
   3:   0x406389 - <no info>
   4:   0x40cc97 - <no info>
   5:   0x657a89 - <no info>
   6:   0x4185b6 - <no info>
   7:   0x6535a1 - <no info>
   8: 0x76f37c04 - BaseThreadInitThunk
   9: 0x77a4ad2f - RtlInitializeExceptionChain
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:106)
    at rms.test.main(test.java:24)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include just enough to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is a good practice to add environment details also. Like **OS info, browser version, selenium version**

Comment: It seems that you are using a capability which the driver couldn't resolve. Could you add your create driver code, with the capabilities options? Thank you.

Comment: os: Windows 10, Browser Version 40x, Selenium - 3.7